# Flutter Post Request to a Flask API

Tags: python, flutter, flask, post, request

i want to send a request Post from my App coded in Flutter in which there is an image converted in Base 64. Here is the following code that I am using :

```
Future<List<Result>> postJSON(String imageP, String iP, String port) async {

  final String jsonEndpoint = "http://$iP:$port/todo/api/v1.0/tasks/mdrv";

  final response = await http.post('$jsonEndpoint', body:
  {
    "id": "3",
    "title_image": "Test",
    "b64Image": "$imageP",
    "done": "false",
  },);

    if (response.statusCode == 200){
      List results = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return results
          .map(
              (result) => new Result.fromJson(result))
          .toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Erreur dans le chargement, veuillez réessayer');
    }
 }
```

But, when i do the request, i have the following TypeError on my Flask API :

```
description = JSON["b64Image"] 
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I am using the following Python code :

```
def send_client():
  Lresult_algo=[]
  JSON = request.get_json()         
  id = JSON['id']
  'description':JSON['b64Image']  
  server=Server(description)       
  description1=server.B64_array(description)
  description2=Image.fromarray(description1)
  description2.save(r"C:\Users\vince\Desktop\test2.png")
  queryPath=r"C:\Users\vince\Desktop\test2.png"
  Lresult_algo=server.send(queryPath)
  maskedBodies_b64 = []
  for matrice in Lresult_algo:
      matrice1=matrice.astype('uint8')
      maskedBodies_b64.append(base64.b64encode(cv2.imencode('.jpg', matrice1)[1]))
  maskedBodies_b64=[str(b64) for b64 in maskedBodies_b64]
  data = {
        'Image_1' : maskedBodies_b64[0],
        'Image_2' : maskedBodies_b64[1],
        'Image_3' : maskedBodies_b64[2],
        'Image_4' : maskedBodies_b64[3],
        'Image_5' : maskedBodies_b64[4]
          }
  resp=json.dumps(data)
  return resp
```

Do you think is this a typing problem ? How could I fix it ?

Comment: It looks like your API is expecting a JSON encoded body, but you are sending a form encoded body. Try encoding the map and use that string as the body. Beware that now you are JSON encoding, that the integer and boolean should perhaps no longer be strings.

Comment: I did change my code and added a json.encode for the body but there is still the same TypeError

Comment: It seems that the API consider the JSON that i am sending as empty

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code like this but there is still the same mistake :

```
Future<List<Result>> postJSON(String imageP, String iP, String port) async {

  final String jsonEndpoint = 'http://$iP:$port/api/v1.0/tasks/mdrv';

  Map<String, dynamic> data = {
    'id': 1,
    'title_image': "Test",
    'b64Image': "$imageP",
    'done': false,
  };

  var client = new http.Client();

  var body = jsonEncode(data);

  var response = await client.post('$jsonEndpoint',headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, body: body,);

    if (response.statusCode == 200){
      List results = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return results
          .map(
              (result) => new Result.fromJson(result))
          .toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Erreur dans le chargement, veuillez réessayer');
    }
}
```